# Android: EditView is moving to right

Tags: android, android-layout

My Activity has one single line EditView, one multi-ine EditView and a Button.
When I enter a long text inside the singleline EditView, the entire form along with the submit Button is moving to right. And I'm unable to submit the form. How can I fix this.

Thanks,
nehatha

+++ Edit +++++++

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg" android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/rootView">
      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/Black" android:layout_height="1dip" />
         <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <LinearLayout
                android:focusable="true" 
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">       
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="12dip" android:paddingRight="20dip"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" android:stretchColumns="0">
        <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="270dip" android:layout_height="270dip">
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
            <EditText android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:focusable="true" android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:hint="@string/hint_title" android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtDesc"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:inputType="text" 
                android:textSize="6pt" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
            <TextView android:padding="3dip" android:textSize="18dip"
                android:textColor="@color/registration_fields_title" android:text="Description" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
            <EditText android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:focusable="true" android:gravity="top" android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:minLines="5" android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/btn_update" android:imeOptions="actionDone" 
                android:textSize="6pt"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:clickable="true" android:background="@drawable/menu_button_border_shape"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:text="Post"
                android:id="@+id/btn_post"></Button>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) (not EditView) is increasing in size thats because its width is set to "wrap_content". Try setting the width to an absolute amount such as:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

or

```
android:layout_width="100dip"
```

`wrap_content` will always be the width of it's content.

Comment: Hi Conn, android:layout_width="fill_parent" is not working for me. I have edited my original post with the actual layout code. can you check once.

Comment: specifying fixed width "300dip" is working fine, but how it will work on different screen sizes..?

Comment: specifying an exact width isn't really recommended unless you know how to make it work for different devices. I really would try to use fill_parent. You say its not working, what exactly is it doing?

Comment: not working means, it is behaving as wrap_content, moving the layout to right

Answer (score 0):

Specify EditText width (e.g. as `fill_parent`)

Comment: "fill_parent" is not working, I have edited my original post with the actual layout code. can you check once.

Comment: @Vencat Try to put fill_parent to TableRow

Comment: I have placed android:layout_width="fill_parent" to TableRow, still the layout is moving right.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try following code

//1)set height of your txtDesc id of EditText
//using fix height
android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
    android:layout_height="70dp"

//or
//2) set height of your txtDesc id of EditText
//using wrap_content height
android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```